# IIS timeout is out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web, connection-timeout

I'm having some trouble setting up a website in IIS. I've bound it to a specific IP address and a port number (11.57.243.296:5), and can browse the site on the server.

If I try to open it over the global network however, it times out (I get error of type `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).

What could the reasons for this be?

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a proper error description. What URL do you use to visit the site, are firewalls allowing traffic (why that low a port?), does the request end up in the log, does traffic from the server itself work, what is the exact error message?

Comment: have you configured the firewall to open whatever ports you have specified?

Answer (score 2):

The local firewall must be configured and ports 80 and 443 must be open.
Go into Windows Defender firewall, incoming, new rule and set it.